# VA01 BDC_OKCODE /00 not working as expected

Tags: abap, sap-erp

In my report I am calling the transaction `VA01` with BDC data, and everything works as expected, the data is being filled correctly, but `bdc_okcode /00` does not work.

I simply add the ok-code to the internal table:

```abap
gs_bdcdata-fnam = 'BDC_OKCODE'.
gs_bdcdata-fval = '/00'.
APPEND gs_bdcdata TO gt_bdcdata.

...

CALL TRANSACTION 'VA01' USING gt_bdcdata.
```

I get a popup that shows the ok code.

[image]

My expectation is that it should navigate to the next dynpro.

Also I tried to record the transaction through the transaction `SHDB` to see if I have to do something differently but the BDC data is basically the same. Playing back the recording shows the same popup with the code.

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MODE addition is not used by the CALL TRANSACTION.
[If one of the additions MODE or OPTIONS FROM is not used, the effect is the same as if mode had the content "A".](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abapcall_transaction_using.htm#!ABAP_ADDITION_3@3@) Which means the call transaction stops by each screen.

It has to be called like this:

```
DATA lv_mode TYPE char1 VALUE 'N'. "N - BI won't stop, E - will stop by error, A - will stop at every screen

CALL TRANSACTION 'VA01' 
     USING gt_bdcdata
     MODE lv_mode.
```

A better option is to use the OPTIONS FROM addition, this gives you more opportunities:

```
DATA: ls_options TYPE ctu_params.

ls_options-dismode = 'N'. "see explanation above

CALL TRANSACTION 'VA01' 
     USING gt_bdcdata
     OPTIONS FROM ls_options.
```